# Reading attribute values from XML file with php

Tags: php, xml

With this XML file with structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element>
    <child attrName="something"/>
</element>
```

i can access with php to read attrName value with expression:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("fileAbove.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    if($child->getName() == "element") {
        $attrValue = $xml->xpath('/element/child/@attrName');
        echo $attrValue;
    }
}
?>
```

So result will be:

```
something
```

But how with this file structure i can't get attrValue with same php code from above?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element someAttr="" otherAttr="">
    <child attrName="attrValue"/>
</element>
```

I'm geting error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

Does anybody know what i miss?
Thank you

Comment: The code example you've provided and of which you say it works *does not work*. Also it contains superfluous code which makes it hard to specifically decipher what you want to ask about. The error you give is not by that code. See as well: https://eval.in/private/3ce2653af7323e

Answer (score 0):

Even with your first example it was returning null.  The below code should solve your issues.

fileAbove.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<element someAttr="" otherAttr="">
 <child attrName="attrValue"/>
</element>
```

readchild.php

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file("fileAbove.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
  foreach($xml->child[0]->attributes() as $a) {
    echo $a . "\n";
  }
?>
```

Result is below:

```
[root@web01 temp]# php readchild.php
attrValue
[root@web01 temp]#
```